# Best way to empty a node using Javascript or YUI?

Tags: javascript, yui

I am doing some autocomplete filtering based on each key press event. This deletes and repopulates large list of div items for every key press. I see the most of the time is taken by the browser to delete the large node list. What is the best way to optimize this?

I am using YUI and doing containerNode.set('innerHTML','') (or containerNode.get('children').remove(true)), 
both are quite slow and freezes browser for a second because it has to trigger on every key press. Plain Javascript or YUI is best, dont want to use jQuery yet.

Comment: i don't think any method is much faster than another, or that it's a slow process, i think it's just getting the blame in your timings for some reason. you can improve insert/removal times by hiding the container. but you should "debounce" the keypress by half a second to keep it from getting over-worked no matter how efficient.

Comment: Thanks. I did some benchmarking and looks like its the addition of dom elements that takes more time. Besides somehow I made each write process to face race condition. So I have put some delay for and also creating node list and putting append only once per key press. That helped a bit. Was wondering how Google instant is so fast!

Answer (score 0):

Cache your divs. If the result from the new set is also in the old set, don't delete the old one.